# Passing Text Box Values from a user control file to another class file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am looking to pass values over from an ascx.cs user control file to another class file in my project. I need to be able to get the values of the dynamic text boxes from the user control to be able to put them in a database.

Here is what I have so far

User Control File

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ItemBox.Text = Request.Form[ItemBox.UniqueID];
        NumberBox.Text = Request.Form[NumberBox.UniqueID];
        DescriptBox.Text = Request.Form[DescriptBox.UniqueID];


    }
```

Other class file

```
 ViewState[VIEWSTATEKEY] = int.Parse(ViewState[VIEWSTATEKEY].ToString()) + 1;
        LoadPageControls();
        RowID ++;

        string box1value = Request.Form[ItemBox.Text];
        string box2value = Request.Form[NumberBox.UniqueID];
        string box3value = Request.Form[DescriptBox.UniqueID];

        string sConnection = generic database address;
```

I have seen other people using a get method to pull the data over. But I can't get the syntax right and it keeps giving errors.

I tried this because I saw it here [C# Get textBox value from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626187/c-sharp-get-textbox-value-from-another-class) and thought it would work, but with no joy

```
string box1value{ get {return ItemBox.Text;} }
```

There is most likely something simple that I am missing here but I have been stuck on this problem for a couple off weeks now and it is driving me up the walls trying to get this project finished so any help that you can give would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your code shows that `box1value` is a read-only property. How did you assign a value to it???

Comment: Post codes that you have tried running and put exact error messages. Don't confuse us with some ill-written codes.

Comment: if you want some values globally accessible then put that in session

Comment: @nikhilsreeni I did read about session values but I'm not sure how they are used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, This is not the best option but i will work

**User Control File

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["ItemBox"] = Request.Form[ItemBox.UniqueID];
    Session["NumberBox"] = Request.Form[NumberBox.UniqueID];
    Session["DescriptBox"] = Request.Form[DescriptBox.UniqueID];
}
```

**Other class file

```
var ItemBox = (Session["ItemBox"] ?? "").ToString();
var NumberBox= (Session["NumberBox"] ?? "").ToString();
var DescriptBox= (Session["DescriptBox"] ?? "").ToString();
```

Comment: This works great. I just need to tinker about with where to put it with all the (!IsPostBack) methods making it a bit cluttered.

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `Request.Form[]` in other class file. Better create another Entity Class with as many properties you need to store values. Create a object of that class in aspx.cs and populate those values. Now pass this object while calling methods from the other class.

Have you run your code? `ViewState` should not either be accessible to any class file other than your aspx.cs file.

Comment: I have ran the code. the only problem is that I need to use this view state because I need to have the dynamically created rows because the users must be able to add new rows to the table whilst keeping the previous data that they have entered into the table. Any other way that I tried to do this, the data was erased every time a new row wad created in the table

Comment: That can be done from the aspx.cs page itself. Why you need another class to add a dynamic row?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35360/ViewState-in-Dynamic-Control

I had found this method on the internet and it worked well for what I needed. But it didn't explain very well how you could pull the data from the viewstate to add it to a database which is where my problem lies now

Comment: Here also they haven't used a seperate class file as it is not needed in this case. Only a seperate method was created within the aspx.cs file itself.

Comment: I guess you question is with passing values to another class file. But nowhere you are mentioning that!

Comment: Ok so you would suggest taking the table out of the user control file, adding it to the page load method in the main  class and then deleting the user control file?

Comment: A particular solution can be coded in thousands of ways. It depends on what logic you are implementing. Unless knowing that, it is hard to tell. By the way, in no case you can delete a user-control file.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. I'm sorry if a seem a bit clueless about the whole subject, but I am only a placement student and have had no training in C# at all so still don't understand a lot of the concepts of User controls and view states which is why its hard to go into detail which may help you guys with the answers but thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your property `box1value` is currently `private` because you haven't mentioned any access modifier. You should add the `public` modifier to it:

```
public string box1value{ get {return ItemBox.Text;} }
```

Comment: That sorted out the error at the start but it still says "item box does not exist in this context" which I assume means that it isn't able to get it from the other class

Comment: You have to declare this property in the class where you have the `ItemBox` control, only then you can extract its `Text`

Comment: Ok i declared that is the user control class and it doesn't give me any errors. How do I then get that value to my main class?

Comment: Add the static keyword as well to your property: `public string box1value{ get {return ItemBox.Text;} }` Now it will be accessible wherever your `UserControl` is accessible by simply `UserControl.box1Value`

Comment: when i add the static value to the string, it gives me an error saying

"An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property"

it then gives me the same message when I try to create a string in the main class using the method you provided above

`string Item = UserControlPart2.box1value;`

Comment: Did you declare the property as static? If yes, can't you access it using UserControlPart2.box1value?